# Advice to minimize memory usage in iPod Touch 2G with iOS 4.2.1

Tags: ipod-touch, memory

Since I updated from iOS 4.0 to iOS 4.2.1 my iPod Touch consumes less memory but still would like to hear some more advices about how to reduce memory leak in my device?

Usually I use Free Memory apps to free up some amount of memory, that is only thing I know.

Note, my iOS it doesn't have multitasking features.

Answer (score 2):

Free Memory apps are a rip off and really dont make your ipod any faster. Try rebooting your device 2 times in a row. And disable any Notifications you have. Disable Bluetooth. And if you aren't using WiFi turn it off.

Comment: While this is a terse answer, it's on point. You can't turn your iPod 2G into an iPhone 4S. iOS is demanding and your system is aging. Additionally, free memory isn't what you're after, but *more* usable memory. iOS handles memory management just fine, allocating as needed. Other than turning of features to make iOS less taxing, there isn't anything else you can do. All other "tricks" are just snakeoil